# concatenate some of the column content and select in one query

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is my film table:

```
FILM (Catalog_Num, Format, Title, Year, Number_Discs, Rating, Timing, Genre)
```

I want to concatenate the genre column if the year is before 1970 and it cannot be repeated, 
for example, if the genre is Romantic --> (Classic Romance) its ok.

but is the genre is already Classic, it should remain Classic rather than (Classic Classic)

after that, I have to list id, title, and genre of all classic film.

Here is what I tried:

```
select genre|| 'Classic'
from film where (year <1970 and genre not in ('Classic'));

select film_id, title, genre
from inventory, film
where film.catalog_num = inventory.catalog_num and genre like '%Classic%';
```

But the output only shows all the genre in classic type, instead of romance classics.
Further, I have to **finish in one query**, but I don't know how to combine them.

Answer (score 2):

Use a subquery to manipulate the data and feed that into your main query:

```
with films as ( 
     select catalog_num 
            , title
            , case
               when (year <1970 and genre not in ('Classic'))
               then 'Classic ' || genre
               else genre end as genre
           from film
  )
select inventory.film_id
       , films.title
       , films.genre
from inventory
     join films on films.catalog_num = inventory.catalog_num
where  films.genre like '%Classic%';
```

Your question says you want *Romantic --> (Classic Romance)* but your posted code has `genre||'Classic` which is the other way round. I have changed the code to generate 'Classic Romance'.

---

Note: you haven't aliased the columns in the second query's projection, so I had to guess which columns come from `film` and which from `inventory`. You will need to correct any wrong guess.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want your definition of class films, then you don't have to munge the genre.  Just do:

```
select i.film_id, f.title, f.genre
from inventory i join
     films f
     on f.catalog_num = i.catalog_num
where f.genre like '%Classic%' or f.year < 1970;
```

If you still want "Classic" in the genre:

```
select i.film_id, f.title,
       (case when f.year < 1970 and f.genre <> 'Classic'
             then 'Classic ' || f.genre
             else f.genre
        end) as genre
from inventory i join
     films f
     on f.catalog_num = i.catalog_num
where f.genre like '%Classic%' or f.year < 1970;
```

Your question is a little vague on whether "Classic" can be part of a genre name rather than the entire name.  So you might want:

```
       (case when f.year < 1970 and f.genre not like '%Classic%'
             then 'Classic ' || f.genre
             else f.genre
        end) as genre
```

Note that such comparisons are usually case-sensitive in Oracle, so you might need to take uppercase/lowercase into account as well.